# Android vuforia with collada file

Tags: android, 3d, vuforia, collada, virtual-reality

I use vuforia to create android application for virtual reality. 
If I have models like .obj I used JPCT library for loading models.

Now I have models in collada file (.dea).
I cannot find any library for loading this collada files.

I there any way to load collada files to vuforia?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Vuforia does not import collada files.
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/technical-what-3d-model-formats-does-vuforia-support

If you use Vuforia in Unity, Unity will handle loading your collada file:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/167548/collada-import-with-textures.html

Update:
The steps you'd need to take are:

1. Download and install [Unity 5](https://unity3d.com/get-unity).
2. Download the Vuforia [Unity bundle](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk). (It's the third option.)
3. Create a new Unity project (File > New Project...) and Import the Vuforia bundle (Assets > Import Package > Custom Package...)
4. FIRST drag the collada textures into Unity's Project pane, followed by the .dae files.

   When you've confirmed this works for you, then you have the larger tasks of migrating your native Android Vuforia project into Unity. This requires moving from Java to C#. Then build and run on Android.

Comment: Could you please add short but complete solution from reference. To keep it on StackOverflow if server won't be available in the future

Comment: Thank you. This solutions is little complicated. There is no 3rd party library for loading collada models into Vuforia? @OntarioBritton

Comment: @MichaelDrdlíček, I updated my answer to explicitly reflect that no, Vuforia does not handle the collada file format.

Comment: @OntarioBritton, in article about supported formats is write that it's possible with 3rd party libraries. Do you know about some library that support this? Thanks.